# How to prove: $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ have the same $T$-annihilator, then so do $f\alpha$ and $f\gamma$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading Hoffman's "Linear Algebra", in $\S7.2$ he mentioned that

Let $f$ be a polynomial, $V\in F^n$, $T\in \mathcal L(V)$, and $\alpha,\gamma \in V$. If $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ have the same $T$-annihilator, then $f\alpha$ and $f\gamma$ have the same $T$-annihilator.

This sounds natural but I'm a bit lost on how to prove that. Could you pls give me some hint?

---

Let me try after Marc's hint:

Let me try. Given the minimal polynomial of $T$-annihilators of $\alpha$,  $\gamma$, $f\alpha$ and $f\gamma$ is $p_\alpha$, $p_\gamma$, $p_{f\alpha}$, and $p_{f\gamma}$. Then $p_\alpha = p_\gamma$ as $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ shares the $T$-annihilator, denoted by $p$.

If $Q_\alpha$ is an annihilator of $f\alpha$, then $Q_\alpha(f\alpha)=0$, so $(Q_\alpha f)\alpha=0$, so $\{Q_\alpha f\}$ is an ideal that is the intersect of $\langle f\rangle$ and $\langle p\rangle$. Same to $\{Q_\gamma f\}$. So these two ideals are the same: $\{Q_\alpha f\} = \{Q_\gamma f\}$, hence would the generator the same: $q_{f\alpha}=q_{f\gamma}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that the $T$-annihilator of$~v$ is defined as the minimal degree monic polynomial$~P$ such that $P[T](v)=0$. And that by $f\alpha$ they mean $f[T](\alpha)$ (applying a polynomial directly to a vector makes no sense). So the $T$-annihilator $Q$ of $f[T](\alpha)$ is the minimal degree monic polynomial such that $Q[T](f[T](\alpha))=0$. Now composition of polynomials in$~T$ corresponds to multiplying polynomials, so you are looking for minimal $Q$ such that $(Qf)[T]$ annihilates $\alpha$. Express that condition in terms of the $T$-annihilator $P$ of$~\alpha$, and then observe that for $\gamma$ you get the same condition (you don't even have to solve the problem of actually finding$~Q$, you just observe that you've got the same problem twice).

Comment: Yes your assumptions are right, sorry I omitted those notations. I've updated the question with my try. Hopefully it's correct?

Comment: Yes it looks basically correct, although I still have some difficulty in interpreting the notation, which does not clearly distinguish between multiplication, application of linear maps and polynomial substitution, and moreover leaves $T$ out of the notation in cases where is it used. But if you manage to not get confused, it is fine.

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided by @[Marc van Leeuwen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/18880/marc-van-leeuwen) is correct and sufficient (and actually helped me read through chapter 7), but just to make the answer closer to complete, let's find the $T-$annihiliator for $f(T)\alpha$.

Notice that $Q(T)f(T)\alpha=0$, therefore $p_\alpha(T) |Q(T)f(T)$ and thus we have to find $Q(T)$ such that $Q(T)f(T)=m(T)p_\alpha(T)$ and $m(T)$ has the least degree possible. We know that $f(T)p_\alpha(T)=(f(T) \quad p_\alpha(T))[f(T) \quad p_\alpha(T)]$ where $(w\quad z),[w\quad z]$ are the greatest common divisor and the $\color{red}{\text{least common multiple}}$ of $z,w$. Therefore $\frac{f(T)p_\alpha(T)}{(f(T) \quad p_\alpha(T))}=[f(T) \quad p_\alpha(T)]$ and we see that $Q(T)=\frac{p_\alpha(T)}{(f(T) \quad p_\alpha(T))}$ is our answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple proof:
Let the monic polynomial $p$ be the common T-annihilator of $\alpha$ and $\gamma$. Let $p_{\alpha}$ be the T-annihilator of $f(T)\alpha$. First, we have
$$p(T)(f(T)\alpha)=f(T)(p(T)\alpha)=f(T)0=0,$$
since $p(T)\alpha=0$. By the definition of T-annihilator, we have
$$p_{\alpha}|p.$$ Thus, we can let
$$p=p_\alpha h_\alpha.$$
On the other hand,
$$p_\alpha(T)(f(T)\alpha)=(p_\alpha f)(T)\alpha = 0$$
Therefore,
$$p|p_\alpha f,$$
and we let
$$p_\alpha f = g_\alpha p.$$
Then we have
$$p_\alpha f = g_\alpha p_\alpha h_\alpha.$$
$p_\alpha$ is monic, so $p_\alpha \neq 0$. Thus we can cancel $p_\alpha$ from both sides of the equation above and get
$$f=g_\alpha h_\alpha.$$
With this result,
$$p_\alpha(T)(f(T)\gamma) = p_\alpha(T) (g_\alpha h_\alpha)(T) \gamma $$
$$= p_\alpha(T) g_\alpha(T) h_\alpha(T) = (p_\alpha h_\alpha)(T) g_\alpha(T) \gamma$$
$$ = g_\alpha(T) p(T) \gamma = g_\alpha(T)0=0.$$
Therefore,
$$p_\gamma|p_\alpha$$.
Similarly, we can derive
$$p_\alpha|p_\gamma.$$
Both $p_\alpha$ and $p_\gamma$ are monic, so $p_\alpha=p_\gamma$.